# Plotting Sin[x] and filling down to the axis when Sin[x] > 0

Tags: plotting, filling

I am trying to plot `Sin[x]` with the option `Filling -> Axis`, but only want the filling if `Sin[x] > 0`.

I didn't find any conditional filling from the documentation. I can only think of the following:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {White, Orange}]
```

Comment: Or similar  way `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, {None, Orange}}}]`,`Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> {0, {None, Orange}}}]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `RegionFunction` and `Show`

```
Show[{
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis,RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, y >= 0]],
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi} ]
}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

One possible way could be:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x] Boole[Sin[x] > 0]}
 , {x, 0, 2 π}
 , PlotStyle -> {Red, None}
 , Filling -> {2 -> {Axis, HatchFilling[1]}}
 ]
```

---

[image]

Comment: +1 Or use `ConditionalExpression` instead of `Boole`; simplifies the `PlotStyle`, i.e., `Plot[{Sin[x], ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], Sin[x] > 0]}, {x, 0, 2  Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> {2 -> {Axis, HatchFilling[1]}}]`

Comment: I think ConditionalExpression is an easier way if we want to change the fill condition e.g. Sin[x]>0.5

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Plot[{Sin[x], ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], 0 <= x <= Pi]}, {x, 0, 
  2 Pi}, Filling -> {2 -> Axis}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

```
Plot[{Sin[x], ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], Sin[x] > 0]}, {x, 0, 
  9 Pi}, Filling -> {2 -> Axis}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: This fails if `{x, 0, 4 Pi}` and does not address the question.

Comment: @Syed, Thank you for bringing that to notice. I've edited my response to the question. Please see the "edit".